# No Image Tags column in my new document library. Why?

Tags: file, properties, modern-document-library, image-tags

Not sure how this column is not showing up by default when I created a new document library and uploaded images.

I want users to be able to tag documents and I have a document library I created that has an image tags column but this particular document library doesn'thave one.

What is it I'm missing?

Microsoft states this - [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/work-with-image-tags-in-a-sharepoint-library-0fd368ae-56c6-478b-99a0-c06be92c1863?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) that it should appear by default.

Comment: It eventually appeared and generated soome tags on docs but not on every document

Comment: Same issue here and no answers from MS. Does anyone know how to add the image tags feature to a library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image tagging feature uses AI to generate tags based on recognizable objects and features in the images.

Some things to consider:

1. It can take a while to deploy after you upload the image. ~1/2 hour
2. Try switching to a different browser to see if that resolves the issue.
3. Check if other document libraries have the same behavior.